# How to awk or grep to filter for strings which have at least 1 number in the first n characters?

Tags: regex, awk, grep

How to filter for strings which have at least 1 number in the first 8 characters and underscore in the 9th character?

My attempt of filtering for alphanumerics does not guarantee at least one numeric is present in the first 8 characters:
`grep "^[a-z0-9]\{8\}_"`

Example of input:

```
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
prod_frontend_1 a55eb34aed85
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
stag_backend_1 52ade8af8cca
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

Target output:

```
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

Comment: With actual regexes, you'll have to write out all 8 possibilities. I think the perl flavor can do it with lookahead though.

Comment: `<input grep -E '^.{8}_' | grep -vE '^[^0-9]{8}'` or `awk '/^.{8}/&&!/^[^0-9]{8}/' input` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude lines without a digit in first 8 characters, and keep only lines with underscore in 9th position. With awk:

```
$ awk '!/^[^0-9]{8}/&&/^.{8}_/' foo.txt 
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

With grep:

```
$ grep -Ev '^[^0-9]{8}' foo.txt | grep -E '^.{8}_'
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

With sed:

```
$ sed -nE '/^[^0-9]{8}/!{/^.{8}_/p}' foo.txt 
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

Comment: It must be said, very elegant!

Comment: It might be safer to use '[:alpha:]` or `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[^0-9]` but that depends on the structure of the input. E.g. this will match: `abc abc1_foo` but we don't know if this is allowed or even possible. Nonetheless, the above answers 100% the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`

updated

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]{8}_/ && substr($0,1,8)  ~ /[[:digit:]]/' file
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```

Comment: This will also match a string that does not contain a number in the first 8 characters.

Comment: OK. Already edited.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```sh
awk 'substr($1,9,1) == "_" && substr($1,1,8) ~ /[[:digit:]]/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation using awk could be:

- Match an underscore at the 9th character using `^.{8}_`
- Match a digit before matching an _ using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)  `^[^0-9_]*[0-9]`

For example

```
awk '/^.{8}_/&&/^[^0-9_]*[0-9]/' file
```

Output

```
zjuscer3_prod_backend_1 5fa9a2774f13
rhg8ik8s_stag_frontend.1 74d419c1c15e
syhvctf4_stag_notebook_1 b846d511c937
```